# Apache2 Virtual Host - two websites on one server, did I configure it correctly?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a server at home that I plan to use to host two websites using Apache, I bought two domains and made them go to my server IP, but the problem is that it only works for one of them, if I enter `domain1.com` it goes to `/domain1`, if I enter `domain2.com` it still goes to `/domain1`.

This is my configs for them, I did this by reading some tutorials and such.. Can you please explain what did I do wrong here?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot "C:\apache\htdocs\domain1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot "C:\apache\htdocs\domain2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is this all what you have in your server config with regard to virtual hosts?

Comment: Yes, everything else is not changed

Comment: Do you have a single or multiple IPs assigned to these two names?

Comment: Don't understand this one. My server has 1 IP, so both domains are linked to it. Single I guess, but don't really understand the question.

Comment: Have a look at this page. It may help you. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I actually took my own from that site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add

> NameVirtualHost *:80

line above the VirtualHost sections

Save httpd.conf and restart httpd